# How to decrypt JSON data in android from node js

Tags: java, android, node.js, json

I try to decrypt to json response in Android from node js server and it does not decrypt it correctly. But it decrypted correctly a string or JSONArray. When i decrypt json object in node js from android, it decrypts correctly. Can you help me to understand what is wrong?

Node js

```
function encryptDataTestWork(text, masterkey) {
// body...
// random initialization vector
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

// random salt
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(64);

// derive encryption key: 32 byte key length
// in assumption the masterkey is a cryptographic and NOT a password there is no need for
// a large number of iterations. It may can replaced by HKDF
// the value of 2145 is randomly chosen!
const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(masterkey, salt, 2145, 32, 'sha512');

// AES 256 GCM Mode
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);

// encrypt the given text
const encrypted = Buffer.concat([
    cipher.update(text, 'utf8'),
    cipher.final()
]);

// extract the auth tag
const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

// generate output
return Buffer.concat([salt, iv, tag, encrypted]).toString('base64');
};

let item = JSON.stringify({name:'Selemani',lastName:'Jimmy'});
let generatedKey = 'SEXFgk1kQ3BcDzrH';

let encryptedMobile = encryptDataTestWork(item, generatedKey);
console.log('data->[encrypted] -> '+encryptedMobile);

res.send({tag: 'success', data: encryptedMobile, key: generatedKey});
```

And Android code

```
private final static int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;


public static String decryptHelper(String algorithm, byte[] cipherText, byte[] tag,SecretKey key,
                                   GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);
    cipher.update(cipherText);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(tag);
    return new String(plainText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

public static String decrypt(String encData, String masterKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    byte[] cipherText;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        cipherText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }else{
        cipherText = android.util.Base64.decode(encData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 0, 64);
    byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 64, 80);
    byte[] tag = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 80, 96);
    byte[] ciphertext = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherText, 96, cipherText.length);
    SecretKey key = getKeyFromPassword(masterKey, salt);
    return decryptHelper("AES/GCM/NoPadding", ciphertext, tag, key, new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, iv));
}
```

Here is what i see in logs

```
Data Response: {"tag":"success","data":"yMiFnU7JNhCtFY1buCO5kGgj8rOm3L+iAr9JxBwziMiPes4mHctcvX+V2crOncOQeLKikGo+RY82mOrKu4DWhhmejdI+/UDHWYqs2k54w4SDED8IeJzZ+1kM5mgB+WMMWI6zb5+9r6TAb6ThBFoE6Ot3dajtvVUe6LwGGiUugViNCGtu","key":"SEXFgk1kQ3BcDzrH"}
```

2022-04-30 12:29:46.298 28249-28281/com.hello.app E/HttpConnexion: n(JSON_OBJECT=key): SEXFgk1kQ3BcDzrH
2022-04-30 12:29:46.337 28249-28281/com.hello.app E/HttpConnexion: Decrypted: "lastName":"Jimmy"}// decrypted text i get. It should be {name:'Selemani',lastName:'Jimmy'}
2022-04-30 12:29:46.338 28249-28281/com.hello.app W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value lastName of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

If i send a string like "Hello World", it correctly decrypts.

Comment: In `decryptHelper()` the return of the `cipher.update(cipherText)` call is ignored, so this part of the plaintext is lost. The correct way would be to concatenate the returns from the `update()` and `final()` calls.

Comment: Note: There are cases where the `update()` call returns nothing (so the code works), but this is not true *in general* (so the code *generally* does not work).

Comment: I have a bug with this.
Sometimes when i encrypt data from Android and try to decrypt it, i get this message.
Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what @Topaco said and it worked!

```
public static String decryptHelper(String algorithm, byte[] cipherText, byte[] tag,SecretKey key,
                                   GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);
    byte[] plain = cipher.update(cipherText);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(plain);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(tag);
    outputStream.write(plainText);
    return new String(outputStream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Thank you! @Topaco You saved me!